# Changing PHP's include and require function?

Tags: php, include, require

I have a software package (7k files) I'd like to deploy on a dedicated server for multiple domains/customers.  Each domain will need some customization.  What I can't think of how to do is use the one code base (for ease of release updates) but add custom files for customer specific needs?

E.G

A file & structure out of the box:

```
/software/admin/modules/sitemap/make-da-sitemap.php
```

If a client has different sitemap needs I want to store a modified file:

```
/customer/admin/modules/sitemap/make-da-sitemap.php
```

Is there a way to have any Include or Require throughout the 7k default files to first look for the file in `/customer/` and use it if it exists, if not use the default?  Am I overthinking this?

** EDIT / REPHRASE ** per Jay's request......

I have some php software that uses the php functions 'include', 'require', 'require_once' .... thousands of times.

I don't want modify every line of code using either of those functions.  By default I'd like to have php check a separate folder for the path in the function before using the actual one defined.  If a file exists there, use it vs the actual path.

Clear as mud? lol

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: The string for the filename being included can be a variable. You could even make a function call that does your check and returns either file based on where it exists or not. `include(check_for_file("whatever.php"));`

Comment: `if(file_exists('/customer/some/file.php')) {//load customer}else{//load default}`??? Put that in your own `make_da_include()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You'll create a class Loader p.ex that will load an INI conf file (or JSON) or in the class itself and instanciate that into the beginning of your file that you want to include.

Or just make the code:

```
if(file_exists('/customer/')) {
$file = //put your path;
}else{
$file = //default path
}

include $path;
```